# Lock circuit of RFID

Tags: filter, comparator, rfid

I am currently in France on an exchange and me and my lab partner have to do an assignment where the goal is to design the lock part of the circuit in an RFID-circuit. Everything here is in French, and we don't speak the language very well yet, hence we have a hard time asking questions to the professors and so on. Now we're beginning to fear that we might not pass this course, and I hope that someone might be able to help.

[image: Circuit]

This is the circuit for what comes after the terminal in the RFID circuit.

The circuit is divided into six parts, as shown in the picture (we think).

1. Oscillator, generates a sine wave with \$f = 3.2768MHz\$.
2. Power unit, transistors that transforms the signal to a square wave signal.
3. RF-filter, bandpass with \$f_c = 3MHz\$, another purpose, if i understand the French in the assignment correctly, is that it "adapts the impedance from the power unit, which is \$8\Omega\$ to the impedance of the terminal which is \$50\Omega\$". Very uncertain of the last purpose..
4. Comparator, figures out if incoming signal differs from the normal signal. This meaning that it detects wether or not the RFID-card is near the terminal. If it is, the signal will be different, and the comparator will detect it.
5. Decoder, checks if the card has the right code to open the door.
6. A circuit element which remembers the state of the door (open/closed), a latch of some sort I guess.

This is what we think so far, but there might be errors.

Our problem now is to find the values of some of the circuit elements (the ones we have to find are marked with xxx where their values should be).

And it is in box 3, 4 and 5 we have trouble. We're not really sure where we should begin.

In box 3 we think that this is some kind of impedance matching between two parts of the circuit, the first part being C3 and L1, and the second part being C4, C5 and L2. \$f_c\$ here would be equal to \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}\$. But we are not sure how to calculate this impedance matching to get this right.

In box 4 and 5 we are clueless, and don't really know where to begin.

Comment: I understand there is some additional descriptive text in this assignment (in French). It certainly gives some hints that are important to solve this, because as it is, it really doesn't seem straightforward (at least to me). I happen to be French, if you add the text to your post, I can eventually translate (I'm not sure I can be more helpful than this however). Also, I suggest you share your concerns about your understanding and your fear to fail the course with your professors. I'm sure they can find specific solutions for your case.

Answer (score 1):

- (3) is a series resonant double tuned BPF with impedance transformer

  - high Q or over sensitive, depends on tolerances and tuning,
  - high current possible limited by driver R which affects Q
    [image]
- (4) is a Half wave divider (think 10:1 probe) with LPF > limiter for envelope

  - define sensitivity needed for amount of hysteresis
  - note (4) will affect loading on (3)
- (5) is a baseband data receiver with R tuned OSC with sync detect and data buffers

now get cracking

P.s. I made the filter searching  for "falstad frequency response" then added parts, select then I edited values and tweaked, but you can do the math on impedance and transfer function 1st.